# X-Frame option working in local system but when deployed in test server it shows response like resource not found

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

X-Frame option working in local system but when deployed in test server it shows response like resource not found. I have used the following configuration in app.yaml:

```
- url: /(.*\.(html|js))$
  static_files: myapp/\1
  upload: myapp/(.*\.(html|js))$
  http_headers:
    X-Frame-Options: deny
```

Comment: The `resource not found` error may indicate inability to access a static file (i.e. unrelated to the `X-Frame-Options` itself). Does the **same** request work if deploying without `http_headers` set? If it doesn't then my suspicion is confirmed - you have some inconsistency between your local execution and your deployed one which you need to identify and address first.

Comment: Thank u for the response. Will you please provide a syntax how to configure x-frame-option in app.yaml